# Which is the more efficient way to shuffle an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, shuffle

Which is the more efficient way to shuffle an array in JavaScript?

Algorithm 1:

```
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Algorithm 2:

```
function shuffle(a) {    
  return a.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
}
```

Please explain your answer!

Comment: Welcome, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Method 2 is going to change the array...maybe. Not necessarily what I'd call a "shuffle", as the new array is not likely to be very random.

Comment: Use the likes of JSPerf online to have a look at performance differences

Comment: please add *your* insights to the question.